# express-validator Break validator chain

Tags: node.js, validation, express, express-validator

I am using express-validator plugin for express

```
var input = {
            'username': {
                notEmpty: true,
                isEmail: {
                    errorMessage: 'Invalid Email.'
                }
            },
            'password': {
                notEmpty: true,
                errorMessage: 'Invalid Password' // Error message for the parameter
            }
        };

    req.checkBody(input);
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        console.log(errors);
    }
```

If I pass username as empty output is

```
[ { param: 'username', msg: 'Invalid param', value: '' },
  { param: 'username', msg: 'Invalid Email.', value: '' },
  { param: 'password', msg: 'Invalid Password', value: '' } ]
```

how to brake the chain if anyone of the validation fails.

Comment: raise a feature request on their github repo

Comment: @hjpotter92 I will delete this question and raise a feature request

Comment: Keep the question here. You can answer it once that request gets a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for this has finally landed in **v3.0.0!**

```js
req.getValidationResult().then( result => {
    var errors = result.useFirstErrorOnly().array();
    // enjoy an array with no duplicated errors for any given parameter!
});
```

---

Update: In newer versions of express-validator you can just pass an option to `validationResult.array()`:

```js
var errors = validationResult(req).array({ onlyFirstError: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to add error message for empty param:

username: {
                notEmpty: {
                    errorMessage: 'Username must not be emtpy'
                },
                isEmail: {
                    errorMessage: 'Invalid Email.'
                }
            }...

Comment: yes thats right but my problem was different and it was a known issue in that library

Answer (score 0):

```
 const validationMiddleware = (
      req: Request,
      res: Response,
      next: NextFunction
    ) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      const locationSet = new Set();
      const paramSet = new Set();
    
      if (errors.array().length) {
        return next(
          new Http400Error(
            errors.array().reduce((total, current) => {
              if (
                !paramSet.has(current.param) ||
                !locationSet.has(current.location)
              ) {
                paramSet.add(current.param);
                locationSet.add(current.location);
                if (total) {
                  return `${total}, ${current.msg}`;
                }
                return current.msg;
              }
              return total;
            }, '')
          )
        );
      }
      return next();
    };
    
    
        export const validateLogin = [
      body('credentialField')
        .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
        .withMessage('Email or User name is required'),
      body('password')
        .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
        .withMessage('Password is required'),
      validationMiddleware,
      body('credentialField').custom(async (credentialField, { req }) => {
        const entity = getCredentialType(credentialField);
        let user = null;
        if (entity === 'email') {
          user = await AuthService.findByEmail(credentialField);
        } else {
          user = await AuthService.findByUserName(credentialField);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return Promise.reject(
            new Error(
              entity === 'email'
                ? 'Email Id or Password incorrect'
                : 'User Name or Password incorrect'
            )
          );
        }
        req.loginUser = user;
        return Promise.resolve();
      }),
      validationMiddleware,
      body('password').custom(async (password, { req }) => {
        const user = req.loginUser;
        const entity = getCredentialType(req.body.credentialField);
        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);
    
        if (!isMatch) {
          return Promise.reject(
            new Error(
              entity === 'email'
                ? 'Email Id or Password incorrect'
                : 'User Name or Password incorrect'
            )
          );
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
      }),
      validationMiddleware,
      body('password').custom(({ req }) => {
        if (!req.loginUser.confirmed) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('You are not verified yet'));
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
      }),
    ];
```